# osCommerce links to categories taking to a wrong page

Tags: hyperlink, oscommerce

I'm modifying a website made with osCommerce (I didn't make this website), and one of the things I have to modify is the look of the home page. My problem is that I have modified the **index.php** file, and all the changes look fine.

However, when I click a link that has been written in PHP with this function:

```
<?php echo tep_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT,'cPath=24&sort=2a') ?>
```

(In `/includes/filenames.php` I have `define('FILENAME_DEFAULT', 'index.php');`.)

What happens is that it shows the correct results, but in a different page, with the old design. I don't understand it, because that link should take me to the same **index.php** that I modified, but obviously it's taking me somewhere else.

I don't know what page is it showing, the only thing I see is the link written by the PHP function:

> (my_catalog_folder)/escaparate-c-24.html?sort=2a&osCsid=p7fp55t489nv042p0ip4mp7si1

I guess that the `tep_href_link()` is writing that, but I don't know what page is using to show the results.

Any clues would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behaviour if the store has the SEO URLs module installed.

Look in the `.htaccess` file and you should spot this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-(.*).html$ index.php?cPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Any and all requests for a category will be rewritten in a friendlier URL string like the one you noted.

As to the use of the older design, double-check the real file being called with an `echo` out of the `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];` or `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];` and make sure the filename and path is correct.

Drop that into a file like `includes/application_top.php` before the final lines (or the closing `?>` if you still have that there):

```
echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
```

It may also be due to caching of the pages. Check to see if there a cache module installed as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I think I figured out where the problem was (thanks to you): in the **.htaccess**. I had this in mine: `RewriteBase /`, a then I changed it to `RewriteBase /sub_folder/`, since the new website is in a subfolder instead of being in the root of the server. Now it seems to work! I hope that I didn't mess up something else for changing that... do you think that could happen? Thank you very much again!

Comment: It'll be fine with your edit. Nothing should break so long as you don't have other files using the same syntax expected by osCommerce @alb